# mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 for windows container not available

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

Why I am not able to pull `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2` for windows container?

I get this error: 2.2: Pulling from dotnet/core/aspnet
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.16299 in the manifest list entries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things wrong here:

1. .NET Core 2.2 has been [out of support](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/microsoft-support.md#out-of-support-net-core-releases) since December 2019 so the manifest tag for 2.2 has been removed from all .NET Core Docker repositories.  It's recommended that you upgrade to a supported version of .NET Core, like 3.1.
2. The error message indicates you're using Windows 10/Server, version 1703 which has been [out of support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Windows%2010%20Enterprise%201703) since October 2019. Updated versions of .NET Core are not being provided for out of support Windows releases, not even if it's a supported version of .NET Core.
3. There have never been Docker images of any .NET Core version published for Windows, version 1703. So there wouldn't even be a way to pull a concrete tag instead of using a manifest tag because no such tag exists.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to get docker for .NET Core 2.2, instead of updating?

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 is still available for download (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.2). While there won't be official container images available for it, since it is out of support, you can still define your own Dockerfiles that install it. Guidance on how to do that is available at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/8fcde60134b83f440c76763f755354208a1034ac/documentation/scenarios/installing-dotnet.md.